# Accessing XLS file issues the error HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-requests, wget

```
import pandas as pd
sheet = 'SENTIMENT'
url = 'https://www.aaii.com/files/surveys/sentiment.xls'
pd.read_excel(url, sheet)
```

HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

```
import wget
wget.download("https://www.aaii.com/files/surveys/sentiment.xls")
```

HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('sentiment.xls', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 1096000680029133238-36223238850220298

How to read with python https://www.aaii.com/files/surveys/sentiment.xls?

Comment: ever solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Code above seems to run fine, but if you are still having problems adding headers helped me in another similar example

```html
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
```